# Не могу понять, почему переменная null

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
 function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  rand = Math.floor(rand);
  return rand;
 }
var exp = document.getElementById ('numa');
exp.innerHTML = randomInteger(6, 9);
</script>
<div id="numa"></div>
```

Может кто подскажет, почему

> TypeError: exp is null

Comment: Потому что `#numa` еще не существует на момент выполнения кода в теге `<script>`.

Comment: Перенесите свой скрипт ниже div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что скрипт расположен перед элементом, а значит, когда он выполняется, указанного элемента еще не существует.
Поменяйте скрипт и html местами и всё заработает:

```html
    <div id="numa"></div>
    <script>
     function randomInteger(min, max) {
      var rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
      rand = Math.floor(rand);
      return rand;
     }
    var exp = document.getElementById ('numa');
    exp.innerHTML = randomInteger(6, 9);
    </script>
```